# SharePoint 2013 - Hide newform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, permissions, form

Is there a way to hide newform.aspx from some users but not all users?  I'm looking for a way to hide the entire form not just fields or columns on the form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with Audience Targeting so the web part on your "NewForm.aspx" page will be invisible to everyone who is not in a specific group.
More Info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33D84CB6-14ED-4E53-A426-74C38EA32293

Click New to open the "NewForm.aspx" page. Then Edit the page (settings gear > Edit Page) Modify the web part for your list. Expand the "Advanced" section of the web part properties where you will find the Audience Targeting section at the bottom of it. Add the Groups of users who should see it and anyone who is not in the groups wont see the content. (Apply > OK for the web part settings, then go to the Page Ribbon > Stop Editing to save.)